# Access to fetch at 'https://open-api.trovo.live/openplatform/channels/id' from origin 'http://localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, cors

I am having a problem with fetching profile data from Trovo API.

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://open-api.trovo.live/openplatform/channels/id' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request
> header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

In the documentation of the API says:

> If you are making API calls from the client side, you may come across
> CORS issues. Your domain needs to be whitelisted in Trovo in order to
> do CORS calls.
>
> In addition, please add origin in the header when you are making
> cross-site calls.

I am getting this error on production too, where I am using my registered domain.

```
const fetchProfile = async () => {
    const ress = await fetch(
      "https://open-api.trovo.live/openplatform/channels/id",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Client-ID": `${process.env.TROVO_CLIENT_ID}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        body: '{"username":"test"}',
      }
    ).then((res) => res.json());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make a proxy call.
On client side u can call :3000/trovo or something like this
And on server side make the call to the server

cli -> server -> trovo -> server -> cli

u encumber load on server, but u avoid cors

Comment: But will this work on production?
Because I have the same problem with this on a production where I use the domain I set on Trovo.

Comment: if you have a server side processor (eg. nodejs, php, java) it works easy, done some times

Answer (score -1):

Your browser is stopping your local site calling any resource not on the same domain.  In your package.json add the line:

```
proxy: "https://open-api.trovo.live";
```

and change your fetch call to be:

```
const ress = await fetch(
      "/openplatform/channels/id", ...
```

However, this will only work in dev and still may not work.  I have not used Trovo so can't say exactly but in Sanity I have to go into the project settings and add all my domains in the CORS/Whitelist section which is what this is saying:

> If you are making API calls from the client side, you may come across
> CORS issues. Your domain needs to be whitelisted in Trovo in order to
> do CORS calls.